# Send file(s) over Network - Can't open recieved file (until Server is closed) because file is used

Tags: c#, file, client-server

I have a simple Client-Server Application. The Client selects a file and this file is sending to the server application over network. The server receives this file and writes it into his folder.
The problem is, that i can't open the received files on the server-side until i closed the server-application.

Client

```
            public partial class Form1 : Form {

                    public string name { get; set; }
                    public TcpClient clientConnection { get; set; }
                    public NetworkStream nws { get; set; }
                    public StreamReader sr { get; set; }
                    public StreamWriter sw { get; set; }

                    public int sizeOfConnectedClients { get; set; }
                    public string clientnamelistString { get; set; }

                    public Form1() {
                        InitializeComponent();
                        connectToServer();
                    }

                    private void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {

                        OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
                        string filename = null;
                        string filepath = null;
                        if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) {
                            filename = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(ofd.FileName);
                            //tbFilename.Text = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(ofd.FileName);
                            filepath = ofd.FileName;
                            //tbFilesize.Text = (new FileInfo(ofd.FileName).Length).ToString() + " KB";
                        }

                        Console.WriteLine("filename: " + filename);
                        var a = File.OpenRead(filepath);

                        FileInfo fo = new FileInfo(filepath);
                        long filesize = fo.Length;
                        Console.WriteLine("Filesize: " + filesize);

                        // Send filename to server
                        sw.WriteLine("Filename: " + filename);
                        sw.Flush();

                        // Send filesize to server
                        sw.WriteLine("Filesize: " + filesize);
                        sw.Flush();

                        // Write file into fileBytes-Array and sends it in parts
                        Byte[] fileBytes = new Byte[1024];
                        long count = filesize;
                        while (count > 0) {
                            int recieved = a.Read(fileBytes, 0, fileBytes.Length);
                            a.Flush();
                            nws.Write(fileBytes, 0, recieved);
                            nws.Flush();
                            count -= recieved;
                        }

                        Console.WriteLine("File sends!");




                    }

                    public void connectToServer() {

                        Console.WriteLine("connect to server...");
                        clientConnection = new TcpClient();
                        IPAddress ipadress = IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1");
                        clientConnection.Connect(ipadress, 5555);
                        Console.WriteLine("connected to server!");

                        nws = clientConnection.GetStream();
                        sr = new StreamReader(nws);
                        sw = new StreamWriter(nws);

                    }
                }
```

Server:

```
            class Server {

                    private IPAddress ipadress;
                    private TcpListener serverconnection;
                    TcpClient clientconnection;

                    public Server() {
                        startServer();
                        waitForClient();
                    }

                    public void startServer() {
                        ipadress = IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1");
                        serverconnection = new TcpListener(ipadress, 5555);
                        serverconnection.Start();
                    }

                    public void waitForClient() {
                        Console.WriteLine("Server startet. Waiting for incoming client connections...");
                        clientconnection = serverconnection.AcceptTcpClient();
                        Console.WriteLine("Client connected with Server!");

                        recieveFile();
                    }

                    public void recieveFile() {

                        NetworkStream nws = clientconnection.GetStream();
                        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(nws);
                        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(nws);

                        while (true) { 

                            // Recieve filename
                            string filename = sr.ReadLine().Remove(0, 10);

                            // Recieve filesize
                            long filesize = Convert.ToInt64(sr.ReadLine().Remove(0, 10));

                            Console.WriteLine("Filename: " + filename);
                            Console.WriteLine("Filesize: " + filesize);

                            long count = filesize;
                            Byte[] fileBytes = new Byte[1024];
                            var a = File.OpenWrite(filename);
                            while (count > 0) {
                                int recieved = nws.Read(fileBytes, 0, fileBytes.Length);
                                nws.Flush();
                                a.Write(fileBytes, 0, recieved);
                                a.Flush();
                                count -= recieved;
                            }

                            a = null;
                            Console.WriteLine("File was written on HDD. Finish!");


                        }


                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the using statement on your readers and writers to ensure everything is disposed from memory properly. example:

```
using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(filename))
{
....do stuff
}
```

Comment: The solution is that i must add "a.Dispose();" to the end of the while-loop on the server-side.